# How to acquire still webcam image

Tags: c#, c++, c, matlab, webcam

I need some help deciding what to use to acquire an image from a webcam. I want to acquire a single image. I know you can typically acquire a still image at a higher resolution than a single video frame.

Currently, I am using MATLAB's image acquisition toolbox.. which apparently only supports obtaining frames in video mode(so lower resolution). Which other libraries do you recommend? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the fact that the largest resolution reported by the Image Acquisition Toolbox is (for example) 1024x768 but the webcam claims that it can acquire 6 megapixel still images?  If so, every webcam that I have ever seen has a note in very small print somewhere that explains that the higher resolution is achieved via software interpolation.

You can just acquire the image in the largest format supported by the toolbox and then use `IMRESIZE` to scale the image to whatever resolution that you want.

Answer (score 1):

We've used WIA at work before.  I can't share our code, but we basically bring up the WIA capture screen (which the user has to interact with before the image is captured).  For an automated solution, have a look at this:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WebCamService.aspx